# i am trying to take shot from ipcamera and open as opencv and convert to numpy formate

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, urllib

use IP Webcam with opencv as a wireless camera
i fallowed this steps
https://thecodacus.com/ip-webcam-opencv-wireless-camera/#.Ws-oS53hXVM
But i need for python3 
i tried my best to do
here my code

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np

url='http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg'
while True:
x=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
imgNp=np.array(bytearray(x.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
img=cv2.imdecode(imgNp,-1)
cv2.imshow('test',img)
if ord('q')==cv2.waitKey(10):
exit(0)
```

But it gives error message
`File "ipcam.py", line 8
    x=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`

I am not Good at python3 help me please

Comment: Add indentation

Comment: what indentation

Comment: i dont know what thai mean

Comment: IMHO that would be lesson 1 in Python: indentation really matters. Sorry to be blunt, but that last sentence seems a serious understatement. Do yourself a favour, forget about OpenCV, numpy and image processing for a while, and take a step back to gaining basic proficiency in the language of choice. Few days of intense study can do wonders. Once you can write and debug basic programs in it, move on to more complex libraries and topics. Just (poorly) copying code you don't understand in a language you don't understand won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Is Sensitive To Indentation..**

Its equivalent to `{}` in C, C++, etc, Think of it as a block of codes to be executed..

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np

url='http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg'
while True:
    x=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgNp=np.array(bytearray(x.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img=cv2.imdecode(imgNp,-1)
    cv2.imshow('test',img)
    if ord('q')==cv2.waitKey(10):
        exit(0)
```

Comment: Pleasure to help kindly accept the answer if it satisfy your requirements.. will add some points to my profile...